# Only first form is posted by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, forms

On my website, I want to have multiple forms for voting on different posts. I've implemented AJAX for this and it's working fine but always only with the first form. I know that I've should change something in my code to do this (something with id's) but honestly, I'm lost. Kindly please advise.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  $("#negative_button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      /* the route pointing to the post function */
      url: '/negative',
      type: 'POST',
      /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller */
      data: {
        _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
        negative_vote: $("#negative_vote").val(),
        post_id: $("#post_id").val()
      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
      success: function(data) {
        $(".writeinfo").append(data.alert);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-right inline">
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
  <input type="hidden" id="negative_vote" name="negative_vote" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
  <input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="{{$post->id}}">
  <input type="button" id="negative_button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Downvote">
</div>

<div class="writeinfo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why only **one** of your buttons works is because of the fact that you are using **ids** to attach a listener to the `click` event. An ID is always a **unique** value. When there is more than one ID with the same value, the first ID is selected and the rest is ignored.

### Classes

Instead use a `class` to identify the buttons or forms. There can be an infinite amount of elements with the same class on the page.

### Form

You are trying to send multiple values at the same time. You can either select each individual `input` element and get their value, or wrap all the `input` fields in a `form` element. This form element can recognize `input` elements inside of it an access their values. It makes it possible to send all of the values in the form at once with more ease.

### Meta

Rewrite the `meta` element as a hidden `input` element. `meta` elements belong in the `head` of the document to give the browser information about the page that it is looking at.

### Submit

A `form` can be *submitted*, meaning that it will send that data inside of it to the destination that you have set. Change the `input type="button"` to `input type="submit"` to use this functionality later on in JS.

For this answer I've rewritten the `meta` element to an `input`, wrapped the `input` elements in a `form` element and added a `class` to the `form` element. Now you can select **all** forms and listen for the `submit` event.

```
<div class="pull-right inline">
  <form class="js-downvote-form" action="/" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="negative_vote" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Downvote">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="writeinfo"></div>
```

Instead of selecting each individual input, we can select all of them together from the `form` element. With the jQuery [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method you can extract all of the values from the form and store it in an object to send in the `body` property.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Listen to submit instead of click on all forms.
  $(".js-downvote-form").on("submit", function(event){

    // Get the values from this form and store it in an object.
    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      /* the route pointing to the post function */
      url: '/negative',
      type: 'POST',
      /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller */
      data: formData, // Your data to send.
      dataType: 'JSON',
      /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
      success: function (data) { 
        $(".writeinfo").append(data.alert); 
      }
    });

    // This is important.
    // We want to override the default submit behavior.
    // So preventing it is necessary.
    event.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Comment: Many many thanks! This so is excellent answer, you've taught me a lot :)

Comment: You are very welcome! :) Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted for others who might land on this thread. Have a good one.

Comment: I've just checked and as I thought everything is working perfectly but... after disabling CSRF. It seems like this token can't get through or can't be read. Any hint about this?

Comment: I think I've got it https://laravel.io/forum/03-01-2015-ajax-token-not-working